# QML displayed camera photos in a ListView are destroyed

Tags: qt, listview, camera, qml, qt5

I take photos with Camera component and add them in a ListView. The problem is that from a certain number of photos, around 10 in my tests, some photo in the list are destroyed and I get the following error:

```
QML Image: Failed to get image from provider: image://camera/preview_7
QML Image: Failed to get image from provider: image://camera/preview_4
```

You can see on the picture that images with index 3 and 6, corresponding to preview 4 and 7, are not displayed, but the delegate is still there as the text element containing the index is created.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
//the Camera
Camera{
  id:camera
  imageCapture {
    onImageCaptured: {
      addPhotoInModel(preview);
    }
  }
}

VideoOutput {
  source: camera
  anchors.fill: parent
}

//the ListView
function addPhotoInModel(image_url)
{
  var imgId= calculateRandomId();

  imagesListModel.append({"photoId": imgId, 
  "value":Qt.resolvedUrl(image_url)});
}

ListView{
  ....
  model:imagesListModel

  delegate:
  Rectangle{
    width:311; height:175;
    Image{
      width:parent.width; height:parent.height
      source:model.value
    }
    Text{anchors.centerIn:parent; text:index}
  }
}
```

If I use a local image instead of photos from the camera, I don't have the problem so I guess it may be a cache problem but why?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct your sample code `with:311:height:175;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using the images which are saved on the disk by camera.imageCapture:

```
Camera{
  id:camera
  imageCapture {
    onImageSaved: {
      addPhotoInModel("file:///"+camera.imageCapture.capturedImagePath);
    }
  }
}
```